# AS3 - Clone class object when class has parameterized constructor

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, cloning

I want to clone a class object. I tried following from [here](http://blog.createdbychristian.com/cloning-objects-in-actionscript-3/):

```
package
{
    import flash.net.registerClassAlias;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class MyClass
    {
        public var property1:String;
        public var property2:Array;

        public function clone():MyClass
        {
            registerClassAlias("MyClass", MyClass);

            var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            bytes.writeObject(this);
            bytes.position = 0;

            return bytes.readObject() as MyClass;
        }
    }
}
```

BUT this only works when the class has a default constructor and not when it has parameterized constructor:

Any idea on how to clone a class object when the class has a parameterized constructor?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I could do for you:

```
package
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;


    public class Thing extends Sprite
    {

        // Cloneable properties.
        private var _cloneable:Array = ["x","y","val1","val2"];


        // Properties.
        public var val1:uint = 10;
        public var val2:String = "ten";


        /**
         * Returns a new Thing with the same properties.
         */
        public function clone():Thing
        {
            var t:Thing = new Thing();

            for each(var i:String in _cloneable)
            {
                t[i] = this[i];
            }

            return t;
        }

    }

}
```

All you need to do is add the properties you want to have clone-able to `_cloneable`

Example use:

```
var thing:Thing = new Thing();

thing.x = 15;
thing.y = 10;
thing.val1 = 25;
thing.val2 = "twentyfive";

// Clone initial Thing.
var thing2:Thing = thing.clone();

trace(thing2.x, thing2.y, thing2.val1, thing2.val2); // 15 10 25 twentyfive
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to not make it too complicated and not over think things.  There really is no need to do anything more complicated than this.

```
 public function clone():Thing {
     var t:Thing = new Thing();

     t.x = this.x;
     t.y = this.y;
     t.val1 = this.val1;
     t.val2 = this.val2;

     return t;
 }
```

and if you have a parameters in your constructor.

```
public function Thing(x:int,y:int) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public function clone():Thing {
    var t:Thing = new Thing(this.x, this.y);

    t.val1 = this.val1;
    t.val2 = this.val2;

    return t;
}
```

I do like the other answer, it's clever but a lot of churn for just setting some properties. Don't over think the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with constructor that has optional parameters. This is a good practice from test driven development and performance point.